# Background Worker inside a class and I have to wait to run again

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've created a background worker.  I works great...until I have to run it again.  It's as though CancelAsync is not immediate and I have to wait.

Here is my work flow to help you understand what I'm doing.

1. Open a file
2. Create an Object that has my background worker logic in it.  It does a bunch of stuff and writes a file.  The worker should end right away, close or self destruct. lol
3. Repeating right after fails to do anything with no errors.  However, the behavior I've witnessed is if I wait about 10 seconds and open a new file to process it works.  It just doesn't like to do right a way.

**From my main form.**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    File_Worker myWorker = new File_Worker();
}
```

**Here is my class**

```
namespace Market.BI.Workers
{
    class File_Worker
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
            Stuff
        }
        void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var myItems      = new List<Part>();
            _CSV_Path        = "somefile.csv";
            var counter      = 1;
            var lineCount    = File.ReadLines(e.Argument.ToString()).Count();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader((string)e.Argument))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    String value     = line;
                    int startIndex   = 0;
                    int length       = 9;
                    String substring = value.Substring(startIndex, length);
                    if (substring == "UDI")
                    {
                        myItems.Add(new Part(line));   <<Part is a structured Class
                    }
                    ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(counter * 100 / lineCount);
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    e.Result = myItems;
        }
        void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stuff
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }

        //Method
        public File_Worker()
        {
            worker.DoWork               += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged      += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted   += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            fileProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the file (stream) not getting closed? Can you show something in the DoWork()? Also what's the error?

Comment: @Tony - I added that detail to my original post.   I do have a close method to my reader.

Comment: @Tony.  There is no error.  What just nothing happens if I try and run that file again.  I just have to wait about 10 seconds for the worker to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. CancelAsync doesn't necessarily finish immediately and you can check if CancellationPending is set to true. You can also check in your Worker_RunWorkerCompleted if e.Cancelled is than true and restart the work.

Comment: When i select the click button the second time.  I quickly debug while the app is running.  What I noticed is the flow goes straight to Worker_RunWorkerCompleted.  It doesn't even hit the DoWork.

Comment: @Pirate from your code example, you create new instance of File_Worker on click, so check the threads. One thread (that apparently hits the DoWork) seems to be from first instance and possible has e.Cancelled set to true, the other is creating new instance of background worker. That is just my assumption, you should try to debug it and pay attention to executing threads, which is doing what. You can also verify the flow with if statement in your Worker_RunWorkerCompleted method, where you check for e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.Result and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried to help me figure this out, thank you.   I'm not so sure I'm answering this question exactly.  I decided to take a different approach to solving my problem by using the TPL. By creating a thread I was able to do the exact samething including updating my progress bar.

Here are some snippets if this will help anybody going forward.

```
var ptx = new Task(() => DoWork(myWorker, fileProgressBar, gridPartEdgeDetails));
                    myWorker.file_Path = filePath;
                    ptx.Start(); 


static void DoWork(CVS_Worker x, ProgressBar pb, DataGrid dg)
{
    var parts = new List<Part>();
    parts     = x.DoMyStuff(pb);  //pass in my progressbar

    //Update Datagrid
    dg.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        dg.ItemsSource = parts;
    });
}
```

And inside my CVS_Worker Class I invoked my status bar from there.  And in the end the coding was simpler and I can launch this process as many times as I want back to back without any issues.

```
pb.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    pb.Value = (counter * 100 / lineCount);
});
```